# How to detect "restrict background usage" with a BASH script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, bash

I have a short bash script in my crontab to run a network-heavy `rclone` backup task.

In psuedocode:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ is_running ]; then
  exit 1;
else
  rclone command;
fi
```

What service, program, or command will return true when I set the current wireless network to "restrict background data" in the wireless manager so that I can add it to the bash script check and not run the `rclone` command? I am running Ubuntu 18.04, Gnome.

[image: screenshot]